# How highlight sql results that are like the keyword

Tags: php, sql, database, highlight

I've seen many posts on google and on this site about the same subject, but i didn't understand any of them. (I'm not very skilled in php yet)

I have the code below to output information about presidents which are saved in a database. The result is in a table. But i want to highlight the keywords in this table. So for example if you search for 'ad' you'll get the 'ad' in 'adams' highlighted.

```
-Name-       -Birth-      -years president-    -died-    
Adams J Q     1767              4                80
```

As i've said before i'm not really skilled so i hope someone can show me what to do. 
Thanks!

The code:

```
 extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP);                                                                                        
    pdo()->prepare($qry);                                                                                               // wat is de query
    pdo()->bindParam(':zoekTerm', "%$zoekTerm%", PDO::PARAM_STR);                                                       // vul parameter in; let op het '' en "" verschil
    pdo()->execute();                                                                                                   // uitvoeren van de query met params


    function getData($qry, Array $bindParameters)                                                                       // haal data uit de query
    {
        pdo()->prepare($qry);
        foreach($bindParameters as $k => &$v) {
            pdo()->bindParam($k, $v, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        pdo()->execute();
        return pdo()->fetchAll();                                                                                       // dus een array (associatief)
    }
                                                                                                                        //print the data from an array

    function prData(Array $data) {

        foreach($data as $k => $v) {
            //print_r($v);
            echo implode( ', ', $v);
        }

    }

    function prDataOp1Regel(Array $data) {
        foreach($data as $r) {

            $d = array();        
            foreach($r as $v) {
                $d[] = $v;          
            }
            print implode('</td><td>', $d); tr();   
        }
    }
    function prDataKeys(Array $data) {      
        foreach($data as  $v) {
            $r = array();                   
            foreach($v as $k => $dummy) {
                $lk = strtolower($k);
                // even iets geks. Omdat het kan.
                if($lk === "gebjaar") $lk = "Geboorte jaar" ;
                $r[] =  Ucfirst($lk);
            } 

            echo    implode ('</th><th>', $r); //nl();
            break;

        }
    }


    $qry = "
    SELECT 
        presnaam AS 'Naam President' 
        ,Gebjaar
        ,Jaarpres AS 'Aantal jaren president' 
        ,Sterfleeftijd
        ,Partij
        ,Staatgeboren AS 'Geboren in'   
    FROM president 
    WHERE presnaam 
    LIKE :zoekTerm 
    "; 

    $d = getData($qry, array(':zoekTerm' => "%$zoekTerm%")); 

    echo '<table id="outputtable"><tr>';
    echo '<th>';
    prDataKeys($d);
    echo '</th>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    prDataOp1Regel($d);
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: I didn't look through your code in detail, but one thing that I noticed, that's unrelated to the question, is you used: if (preg_match(X,Y)) { ... } if (!preg_match(X,Y)) { ... } . Instead you should use: if (preg_match(X,Y)) { ... } else { ... } . It uses less resources and is less likely to have errors after updates.

Comment: Instead of posting the complete code and expecting people to go through it, could you cut it down to the parts relevant to your question? That would make it easier for people to help you out and you'll receive quicker response

Comment: echo implode('</th><th>', $r); should be echo '<th>'.implode('</th><th>', $r).'</th>'; And '<td>' and '</td>' should be used for the row values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preg_replace or str_replace to replace the string that was being searched on with some html that you can format using css.

For example, "Adams" would be replaced with something like "<span class='match'>Ad</span>ams" or "<strong>Ad</strong>ams" if the search was for "Ad".

EDIT:

In your function prDataOp1Regel, you can perform the string replacement at the line:

```
$d[] = $v;
```

This line would become:

```
$d[] = str_replace ( $searchStr , "<span class='match'>{$searchStr}</span>" , $v);
```

However, you'd need to update your function definition to take in the search string as a parameter:

```
function prDataOp1Regel(Array $data, $searchStr) {
```

Also, you shouldn't do a search and replace for every row and column, it should only be done for the column that is being searched on. If the $data array is an associative array where the column names are the key for each value in the column you can change the code so that it is something similar to:

```
foreach($r as $columnName => $v) {
    if ($columnName == 'Naam President') {
        $d[] = str_replace ( $searchStr , "<span class='match'>{$searchStr}</span>" , $v);
    } else {
        $d[] = $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Your answers was what i found on google, but i don't know what/where to change it exactly. I did not write this code so some parts aren't clear to me yet.